# iOS APNS App and App Clip common push notification topic

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-appclips

I have push notifications setup for my app and it’s corresponding App Clip. Let’s say that the App has an AppID, com.X and the App Clip has the ID com.X.Clip.

I set the topic of the aps to com.X.Clip to send push notifications to my App Clip and it works properly. However, when I try to send push notifications to my App, I get the error DeviceTokenNotForTopic because the device token is for the AppClip and not for the app. Fixing the topic to com.X, solves the problem.

My question is, is there a way to set the topic to something common that can be shared by my App and the AppClip so that I don’t receive these errors? Otherwise I would have to also store which device tokens are for the app and which are for the clip which will increase storage costs.

Or perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out, but I just asked a similar question here: [How do I detect whether an iOS App Clip or Universal Link is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74294094/how-do-i-detect-whether-an-ios-app-clip-or-universal-link-is-running)

You can't combine them, but you can tell your server where to register the device token.