# How do I detect whether an iOS App Clip or Universal Link is running?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, apple-appclips

I want to set up the same URL to be used as an App Clip URL and as a Universal Link at the same time. Both are very similar in that application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) is invoked and the activity type is "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb".

However, because I'm registering the app for notifications, I need to know whether the app or the app clip is being run so that the server can register the device for the right one.

I'm thinking the best way to do this is to compare the running app's bundle ID to the app clip's bundle ID to know if it's the app clip that's running.

```
if NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier == "myAppClipBundleId" {
    // let the server know
}
```

Is that the "best" way to do it, or is there something more robust?

Thanks!